How to do this limit $L=\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,4)} \frac{y^2 - 4xy}{y^2 - 16x^2}$
Evaluate :
$$L=\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,4)} \frac{y^2 - 4xy}{y^2 - 16x^2}$$
My Work :
We can cancel $(y-4x)$ from the numerator and denominator provided $y \neq 4x$ and this comes out as $1/2$.
When the function is evaluated along $y=4x$ it is undefined (i.e. $f(x,4x) = 0/0)$.
This means the limit cannot exist along this line, right?
Therefore the limit $L$ does not exist?
Is my thinking wrong?

The limit is $1/2$. The limit is the thing that refers to particular point (here $(1,4)$) and when you evaluate it the only thing of your concern is the surrounding of that point that is in the domain of the function, but line $y = 4x$ is not so you ingore it.

For the function to have a limit at $(1,4)$ it must be defined in a open disk centered at $(1,4),$ except possibly at $(1,4).$

Usually, when a function is undefined on a parrt of the rregion, we take the limit to be oof pooints only in the parts where the function is defined, as long as there arre "enough" points near the llimit point, here $(1,4)$ where the function is defined.

The limit is defined as follows:

Let $f\colon A\to\Bbb R$ (where $A\subset\Bbb R^2$) be  a function and $(x_0,y_0)$ be a limit point of $A$. Then, say $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=L$$if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$f(B_{\delta}(x_0,y_0)\cap A)\subset B_{\varepsilon}(L)$$

In your case, $A$ is all of the plane except the line $y=4x$, but as only the region where the function is defined matters, the limit is $1/2$. It is precisely the same reason as why $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ is $2$.
Hope this helps. :)

$L= \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,4)} \frac{y^2 - 4xy}{y^2 - 16x^2} = \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,4)} \frac{y(y - 4x)}{(y - 4x)(y+ 4x)}$. Now as $(x,y) \to (1,4)$. Now  $y - 4x \neq 0$ at $B((1,4),\delta) \setminus \{(x,y) : y = 4x\}$. Where $B((1,4),\delta)$ is a open ball or neighbourhood of $(1,4)$, for some $\delta >0$ which contains the line $y = 4x$. As on this line, our function is not defined, but we can still find the limit by removing that line from the neighbourhood.
So $L = \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,4)} \frac{y}{y+ 4x} = \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$.
